# Does .SVC file go with Service with Client Solution?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-7, web-hosting, wcf-hosting

I am writting the WCF service for the first time and my team follows the practice to host the service in IIS using .SVC files. So far so good.

Now the kind of project I have is as following:

- A WCF project solution
- A client Solution with multiple projects

Now, as I saw in tutorial .SVC file is contained in a WCF website project which is add refers to the WCF service as a DLL Which makes a strong case for having this .svc file in WCF project. However, I wanted to make sure that I am thinking straight and I am following industry practices by adding hosting environment in the same solution where WCF project is contained. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Are you asking how to reference the WCF service in your client solution?

Comment: No, where to include "WCF service website project". Would it be in the solution that contains WCF Service or in the solution that contains client projects?

Comment: I apologize, I still don't have a clear understanding of what you're asking. Generally speaking, if you are consistently making changes to a WCF service project in conjunction with client changes, it's a good idea to keep them in the same solution. It just makes it easier in the developer so they don't have to have two instances of visual studio going.